# OpenCV minAreaRect for character deskew

Tags: opencv

I am implementing a system that needs to deskew characters before recognition. I am currently using OpenCV's minAreaRect to obtain the best rectangle containing the character. I use this rectangle's coordinates to apply warpPerspective transform, so it has to be accurate.

The problem is that for some characters this minAreaRect does not return the best position for the characters, as seen here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ibxi.png
Note that the red contours are the minArea rectangle and the green ones the contour itself.

I tried to verify the area of the T box and it appears to be similar to a straight box containing T. Is this the expected behaviour of this function?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is common behaviour for `minAreaRect()`. You'll also encounter this problem with the 7 for instance. A common way to solve this is to find the [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) of the characters.

A simple way to do this would be to iterate over your `rotatedRect` objects and store the angles of the shortest sides and sizes. Then place a `rotatedRect` of the most common angle and size and replace the outliers with this.